# 14.04 windows go off screen on awake

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, display, laptop, window

I currently have a dual monitor setup running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. My display settings are currently set to have my laptop screen on the right and my monitor on the left.

Whenever I open the lid of the laptop to awaken it from sleep mode I have a strange problem. All of the maximized windows on my laptop screen get moved over to the second monitor's screen and all of the other windows on the laptop screen get moved far off the laptop screen to the right. I am able to locate these windows using Alt-Space and move them back to the screen using the arrow keys, but it gets very annoying doing that every time I sleep the computer. Any ideas on how to fix this?

I hope that is a descriptive enough presentation of the problem. If anything needs clarification, please ask.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your `System Settings` - `Display` and a copy of your `~/.config/monitors.xml`?  (If you can't post any screenshot, just post the link without the H T T P : / / and I'll edit it in)